# What is the best way to destroy packed ice?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I currently "*live*" in a Ice Plains Spikes biome and I need to terraform a big chunk of area full of ice spikes. What is the best way to **destroy** (not collect) packed ice blocks?

Comment: Are you looking to collect packed ice, or just destroy it?

Comment: What are Ice Spikes? Are you using any mods? Because there is no Ice biome or Ice Spikes in Vanilla Minecraft.

Comment: @Aaron128l yes there is.  It was introduced in 1.7

Comment: Sorry about that so many biomes added.

Comment: @MBraedley Destroy, as stated in the question body.

Comment: Apparently lava doesn't do any damage either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing a lot of research, at the moment there is no true tool to destroy packed snow. While the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Packed_ice) says

> They can be obtained using any tool with the silk touch enchantment.

It doesn't say the speed about any tool.
In relation to Ice the efficiency 5 pickaxe would be the way to go. But According to the [Mojang Bug Report Site](https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC-34772) that does not work that same way. Based on what Carl Lystad said :

> I would say Works as Intended, as efficiency only applies to blocks that the tool is normally faster at breaking. Packed Ice, like regular Ice, does not have a specific tool that is faster at breaking it, so efficiency will have no benefit.
> Efficiency was changed back around 1.5 (I forget the exact version that changed it, but I think that's right) from its previous behavior, which would have produced the effect you are looking for.

I believe this anwsers your question. Also Ice Plains Spikes Biome.